# Can't figure out MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

My SQL statement looks like this

```
SELECT q.content 
FROM questions AS q, user_question_assoc AS uqa 
WHERE uqa.user_id=? AND (q.course_id = uqa.course_id 
OR q.lesson_id=uqa.lesson_id
OR q.question_id=uqa.question_id)
```

Last part of statement is not as I need

```
WHERE uqa.user_id=? AND (q.course_id = uqa.course_id 
    OR q.lesson_id=uqa.lesson_id
    OR q.question_id=uqa.question_id)
```

Actually I want to figure out 1 and only MySQL statement from followings (I tried to explain in human language))

If `uqa.question_id` not 0 (or NULL) then

```
WHERE uqa.user_id=? AND (q.course_id = uqa.course_id 
        AND q.lesson_id=uqa.lesson_id
        AND q.question_id=uqa.question_id)
```

If `uqa.lesson_id` not 0 (or NULL) but `uqa.question_id` is 0 then

```
WHERE uqa.user_id=? AND (q.course_id = uqa.course_id 
        AND q.lesson_id=uqa.lesson_id)
```

If  `uqa.course_id` not 0 (or NULL) but `uqa.question_id` and `uqa.lesson_id` are 0 then

```
WHERE uqa.user_id=? AND q.course_id = uqa.course_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use case when like:

```
WHERE (CASE WHEN xx is not null then xid when yyx is null the yid end) = (CASE WHEN ww is null then someother id else id end)
```

I do not know the syntax in MySQL, but this is how it could be done in Oracle or MS sql

Answer (score 1):

Some databases, such as MySQL will not use indexes if you use the `OR` clause. Using `UNION` instead may perform much better with large tables:

```
SELECT
    1 AS id,
    q.content 
FROM 
    questions AS q
INNER JOIN
    user_question_assoc AS uqa ON 
        q.course_id   = uqa.course_id AND
        q.lesson_id   = uqa.lesson_id AND
        q.question_id = uqa.question_id
WHERE 
    uqa.user_id     = ? AND
    uqa.question_id <> 0
UNION
SELECT 
    2 AS id,
    q.content 
FROM 
    questions AS q
INNER JOIN
    user_question_assoc AS uqa ON 
        q.course_id   = uqa.course_id AND
        q.lesson_id   = uqa.lesson_id
WHERE 
    uqa.user_id     = ? AND
    uqa.question_id = 0
UNION
SELECT 
    3 AS id,
    q.content 
FROM 
    questions AS q
INNER JOIN
    user_question_assoc AS uqa ON 
        q.course_id   = uqa.course_id
WHERE 
    uqa.user_id     = ? AND
    uqa.question_id = 0 AND
    uqa.lession_id  = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should do this using proper join syntax:

```
SELECT q.content
FROM questions q join
     user_question_assoc uqa
     on (q.course_id = uqa.course_id OR
         q.lesson_id=uqa.lesson_id OR
         q.question_id=uqa.question_id) 
WHERE uqa.user_id=?
```

Now try this:

```
SELECT q.content
FROM questions q join
     user_question_assoc uqa
     on q.course_id = uqa.course_id AND
        (q.lesson_id=uqa.lesson_id OR coalesce(uqa.lesson_id, 0) = 0) AND
        (q.question_id=uqa.question_id or coalesce(uqa.question_id, 0) = 0) 
WHERE uqa.user_id=?
```